# How to make a XIB file to wrap its content

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have the following Xib File for a custom view ():

```
Simulated Metrics / Size = Freeform
```

[image]

But if I increase the label's font size the view does not resize:

[image]

Tried adding a constraint to the bottom but it resizes the label instead of the parent view.

[image]

How can I make the XIB root view to resize according to the constraints and intrinsic sizes of the elements inside?

Comment: If you want the xib to autoresize while you're editing that won't happen.
Although if you make this into a UIControl and then make the properties `IBDesignable` you could see it resize

Comment: The root view won't resize automatically. IB does not have enough information for that because the size depends on the superview that is unknown. The constraints will be there though, therefore if you add the view correctly to another view, the autoresizing will work.

Comment: parent view never resize . you need to resize it manually . if you add bottom then label resize then it is the right constraints connect to view. now do change parentview size using interface builder or programatically.